Не обновляет метаданные Rank match SEO
Всем доброе время суток!
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.
Поставил себе на сайт Rank match SEO, но он не работает на сайте, не обновляет метаданные и ключевые слова если стоят постоянные ссылки: произвольно либо название записи. Работает только с простыми ссылками по типу /?p=123. То-есть если установить простые ссылки, то rank match seo работает корректно и устанавливает ключевые слова и метаданные.

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress
